# How to add | after every second number in string

Tags: javascript

Is there a regular expression to add this | symbol after every second number in string.

Have tried split join, filtering the string but with no luck

```
let str1 = "Plymouth Belvedere 1968,1969 Plymouth GTX 1968,1969 Plymouth Road Runner 1968,1969 Plymouth Satellite 1968,1969"
```

Results should be

```
Plymouth Belvedere 1968,1969|Plymouth GTX 1968,1969|Plymouth Road Runner 1968,1969|Plymouth Satellite 1968,1969|
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you add your attempts to your question?

Comment: `str1.replace(/(\d{4},\d{4})/g, '$1|')`

Answer (score 3):

You could look for decimals with comma and replace it with a pipe.

```js
let string = "Plymouth Belvedere 1968,1969 Plymouth GTX 1968,1969 Plymouth Road Runner 1968,1969 Plymouth Satellite 1968,1969",
    result = string.replace(/\d+,\d+/g, '$&|');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace

```
\D*\d+\D*\d+
```

[image]

```js
let str = "Plymouth Belvedere 1968,1969 Plymouth GTX 1968,1969 Plymouth Road Runner 1968,1969 Plymouth Satellite 1968,1969"


let final = str.replace(/\D*\d+\D*\d+/g, "$&|")

console.log(final)
```

Comment: why a character class?

Comment: @NinaScholz `Is there a regular expression to add this | symbol after every second number in string.` considering a general case where numbers aren't consecutive

Answer (score 1):

```
let str1 = "Plymouth Belvedere 1968,1969 Plymouth GTX 1968,1969 Plymouth Road Runner 1968,1969 Plymouth Satellite 1968,1969";

let str2 = str1.replace(/\d+,\d+/g, "$&|");
str2 = str1.replace("| ", "|");
```

The first replace replaces numbers with the same numbers followed by a `|`. The second replace removes the spaces after `|`.

For the regular expression `/\d+,\d+/g`, `\d` matches all numbers, `+` means that there is at least 1 digit but there can be more, `,` is for the comma that you have between the numbers, `g` ensures that it iterates through the whole string, and `$&` reinserts the matched string.

Answer (score -1):

So the [pattern](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%5Cd%7B4%7D%2C%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%2Fg) you want to match is 4 numbers comma 4 numbers

```js
let str1 = "Plymouth Belvedere 1968,1969 Plymouth GTX 1968,1969 Plymouth Road Runner 1968,1969 Plymouth Satellite 1968,1969"
var res = str1.replace(/(\d{4},\d{4})/g, '$1|')
console.log(res)
```